# point to function in memory depending on context - polymorphism

Tags: c, oop, pointers, polymorphism

I would like to call a function depending on the context, it's the polymorphism idea I just can't seem to grasp.

Is following example a plausible solution? where you create a struct and point to relevant function depending on Context:

*I know I should allocate memory for the stuct, which I am not doing in this pseudo code*

```
struct ContextMethods{
   void (*memberMethod)();
} ContextMethods;

void debugFunction(){ returns debug info};
void productionFunction( does usefull production stuff);
void run(ContextMethods local_context);

main(){

    struct ContextMethods local_struct;

    if(DEBUG){
        local_struct->memberMethod = &debugFunction;
    }
    if(PRODUCTION){
        local_struct->memberMethod = &productionFunction;
    }

    run(local_context);
}

run(local_context){
    local_context->memberMethod();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you *should* allocate your struct on the heap? the way you use it, it is totally fine to have it on the stack. Just don&#39;t treat your struct as a pointer and access its members like `local_context.memberMethod()` . in fact, you should *avoid* allocating memory unless really required. in your situation, there is no need to have your struct on the heap, thus *do not* allocate it. have the compiler manage the object instead.  Apart from that - fine use of function pointers.   what should you require function pointers for if not for deciding at runtime which function to call?

Comment: thanks, noted, appreciated

Comment: you are welcome. just to clarify: entirely fine usage of function pointers. if you want to read  a bit more about advanced techniques like these, I can recommend "21st century C" - forgot the author though...